# Ошибка в преобразовании типов, как починить?

Tags: c#, wpf, строки

```
string[] tempConten = _context.Library.Local.ToObservableCollection().Select(s => s.inscription);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.ToArray()` в конец выражения?

Comment: Сейчас да, но он не видит элементы из бд

Comment: Добавил новый скриншот видно что элементов массива нет

Comment: **notice**. не стоит в заголовке или теле вопроса писать "нужна помощь", "HELP" и пр. Т.к. все, кто сюда приходит, нуждается в помощи...

Comment: Данные в `Local` предварительно загружены? Вызовом метода `Load`.

Comment: Да данные загружены